# FragmentPagerAdapter implementing LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, fragmentpageradapter

Im trying to implement a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a cursor loader.  However, it seems that I am unable to access the cursor within `getItem()` as I get a null reference error when attempting to access the cursor as it is not been set yet in `onLoadFinished()`.

Will `onLoadFinished()` not complete until `getItem()` is finished?

Is there a better way to load the cursor data?  I can query the `ContentProvider` directly and store the results in my cursor, but thought a loader is preferred.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private Cursor cursor;


public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 13;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    Bundle args = new Bundle();


    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    args.putString(TextViewFragment.TITLE, cursor.getString(1));
    args.putInt(TextViewFragment.POSITION_KEY, position);
    return TextViewFragment.newInstance(args);

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Fragment # " + position;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), TestContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cursor = arg1;
    //throw new IllegalArgumentException("We are HEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHEREHERE");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the Loaders in the fragment instead of the adapter and probably a method to activate it.
Try running the loaders in the activity and updating the ViewPager adapter using FragmentStatePageAdapter (works like a list adapater) instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.